# Filter function

Tags: php, function, filter, return, break

I have a filter function which is supposed to check two "fields" in an array, these are cold *name* and *description*.

I also have words stored in a database which the filter function should accept certain words (true) and decline certain words (false).

Example:
Every post coming in containing the word **car** should be accepted.

In the database I have stored following words which is accepted:
car (obviously)

Not accepted:
truck
traktor 
buss

So I have a function that is supposed to go through the two fields (*name* and *description*) in the array match them to the words stored in the database and look if the fields contains the accepted word or any of the not accepted words.

My function looks like this
$arr = incoming array with the fields *name* and *description*.
$a['value'] = If it is 0 the word is not accepted if it is 1 the word are accepted.
$a['filter'] = The word from the database.

```
function checkFilter($arr)
{
    $name = strtolower($arr['name']);
    $description = strtolower($arr['description']);

    $dbh = $this->connect();    
    $rs = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM filter");
    $rs->execute();
    $all = $rs->fetchAll();

foreach($all as $a)
{
    if($a['value'] == 0 && strstr($name, strtolower($a['filter']), true))
    {
        return false;
        break;
    }

    if($a['value'] == 0 && strstr($description, strtolower($a['filter']), true))
    {
        return false;
        break;
    }

    if($a['value'] == 1 && strstr($name, strtolower($a['filter']), true))
    {
        return true;
        break;
    }

    if($a['value'] == 1 && strstr($description, strtolower($a['filter']), true))
    {
        return true;
        break;
    }
}
return false;       
}
```

As you se my thought here is, if any of the not acceptable words are showing up I want to return false from the function and break. This because it doesn't matter if the accepted word is in the *name* or *description* if the not accepted word is already there.

After the foreach I have a return false because if it can't find the accepted word (eg car) it should be filtred out.

My problem is that this doesn't seems to work. It doesn't seems to break the function after it hase come into an if statement.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Should the existance of either an accepted or unaccepted word negate the effect of the other. I mean, what should happen if both an accepted unaccepted word are present?

Comment: If not accepted words are showing up an accepted word should not be taken in consideration. So example: "A blue truck car is driving" Here car is in but because truck is it should return false. Other example "A blue car is driving". This should return true.

Comment: What happens if neither is there. "A blue Ford is driving"

Comment: Then - my thought is - that it should return false. You se the last return false outside the foreach.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem in english first, then in code. Looks like the logic you need is `if (good && !bad){return true;}else{return false;}` Is this correct?

Comment: Okay, I'm at work right now and can't commit too much time on it, but if no-one answers before I get to it, I'll try to help you this evening.

Comment: Thanks TecBrat, thats much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkFilter($arr)
{
$good=false;
$bad=false;

    $name = strtolower($arr['name']);
    $description = strtolower($arr['description']);

    $dbh = $this->connect();    
    $rs = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM filter");
    $rs->execute();
    $all = $rs->fetchAll();

foreach ($all as $a)
  {
    if($a['value']==0)
      {
        if(strpos($name,$a['filter']!=='false') || strpos($description,$a['filter']!=='false') ){$good=true;}
      }
    if($a['value']==1)
      {
        if(strpos($name,$a['filter']!=='false') || strpos($description,$a['filter']!=='false') ){$bad=true;}
      }    
  }

return ($good && !$bad);
}
```

Comment: If I reversed your good and bad fields, just swap the $good=true and $bad=true

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer TecBrat. I modified your example a bit and got it to work. Now it looks like this:

```
function checkFilter($arr)
{
    $name = strtolower($arr['name']);
    $description = strtolower($arr['description']);

    $dbh = $this->connect();    
    $rs = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM filter");
    $rs->execute();
    $all = $rs->fetchAll();

    $bad = 3;
    $good = 3

    foreach ($all as $a)
    {
        if($a['value']==0)
        {
            if((strpos($name, strtolower($a['filter']))!==false) || (strpos($description, strtolower($a['filter']))!==false))
            {
                $bad = 0;
            }
        }

        if($a['value']==1)
        {   
            if((strpos($name, strtolower($a['filter']))!==false) || (strpos($description, strtolower($a['filter']))!==false) )
            {
                $good = 1;
            }
        }    
    }

    if($good == 1 && $bad != 0){
        return $good;
    }
    else
    {
        return $bad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you switch from booleans to integers?